# Why is the bind not triggering when i press the left or right key? Tkinter

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

When I press the right or left key, the bind in move_ball doesn't get triggered.

Is this something to do with the OOP side or the Tkinter side?

Can .bind be anywhere in the code or does it need to be in the same class?
Any help?

This is to allow me to post because apparently I don't have enough details.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



class Paddle():
    def __init__(self, canvas, height, width):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def movement(self, amount, canvas):
        if self.coords(self)[0] >= 51:
            canvas.move(self, -amount, 0)
        elif self.coords(self)[0] <= 551:
            canvas.move(self, amount, 0)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Brick:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Game():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry("1000x500")
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 400, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack(pady=20)
        self.direction = "up"
        self.x = 4
        self.y = -4


    def generate_images(self):
        self.image1 = Image.open("/Users/gustavsstutins/GitRepos/COMP16321-Labs_y81328ks/red_rect.png")
        self.image1 = self.image1.resize((100,50))
        self.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image1)
        self.paddle = Paddle(self.canvas, 300, 360)
        self.paddle = self.canvas.create_image(self.paddle.height, self.paddle.width, anchor=CENTER, image=self.image1)
        
        self.image2 = Image.open("/Users/gustavsstutins/GitRepos/COMP16321-Labs_y81328ks/gold_ball.png")
        self.image2 = self.image2.resize((30,30))
        self.image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image2)
        self.ball = self.canvas.create_image(300, 330, anchor=CENTER, image=self.image2)

        self.image3 = Image.open("/Users/gustavsstutins/GitRepos/COMP16321-Labs_y81328ks/blue_rect1.png")
        self.image3 = self.image3.resize((100,30))
        self.image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image3)
        self.rect1 = self.canvas.create_image(300, 70, anchor=CENTER, image=self.image3)


    def left(self):
        if self.canvas.coords(self.paddle)[0] >= 51:
            x1 = -15
            y = 0
            self.canvas.move(self.paddle, x1, y)

    def right(self):
        if self.canvas.coords(self.paddle)[0] <= 551:
            x2 = +15
            y = 0
            self.canvas.move(self.paddle, x2, y)

    def move_ball(self):    
        self.canvas.bind("<Left>", self.left)
        self.canvas.bind("<Right>", self.right)
        
        #can put this all under one condition statement---
        if self.canvas.coords(self.ball)[0] >= self.canvas.winfo_width() - 15 and self.direction == "up":
            self.x *= -1
        elif self.canvas.coords(self.ball)[0] >= self.canvas.winfo_width() - 15 and self.direction == "down":
            self.x *= -1
        elif self.canvas.coords(self.ball)[0] <= 15 and self.direction == "up":
            self.x *= -1
        elif self.canvas.coords(self.ball)[0] <= 15 and self.direction == "down":
            self.x *= -1
        #-------
    
        if self.canvas.coords(self.ball)[1] <= 15 and self.direction == "up":
            self.y *= -1
            self.direction = "down"
        elif self.canvas.coords(self.ball)[1] >= self.canvas.winfo_height() - 15 and self.direction == "down":
            self.y *= -1
            self.direction = "up"
        
        
        
        self.ball_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.ball)
        self.overlaps = self.canvas.find_overlapping(self.ball_pos[0], self.ball_pos[1], self.ball_pos[0], self.ball_pos[1])
        if 1 in self.overlaps:
            self.direction = "up"
            self.y *= -1

        self.canvas.move(self.ball, self.x, self.y)
        self.canvas.after(25, self.move_ball)



window = Tk()
my_game = Game(window)
my_game.generate_images()
my_game.move_ball()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to do the `.bind()` calls on the window itself, as the Canvas won't have keyboard focus and therefore won't have keyboard events delivered to it.

Comment: I tried changing it to .window.bind() but this didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a canvas widget by default does not get the keyboard focus, so it will not see any keyboard events. You can give it the keyboard focus by calling `focus_set` on the widget.

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self, window):
        ...
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 400, bg = "white")
        ...
        self.canvas.focus_set()
```

Comment: self.canvas.focus_set() didn't fix it, I tried it with .focus() aswell.

Comment: @GStut: are you certain it didn't work with the exact code in your question? The problem is definitely a matter of keyboard focus, and this is how you change keyboard focus. Now, the code you posted has an error when you press the keys (`left` and `right` need to accept an `event` parameter), but that's a separate problem.

Comment: I'm placing self.canvas.focus_set() at the end of my constructor right? That's what I did. It shows a little black border on the canvas but my left and right keys still aren't triggering it?

Comment: @GStut: have you checked the console to see if there are errors? The paddle won't move because of the errors, but `right` and `left` are being called. If you're seeing the black border then the canvas is being given the focus properly.

Comment: I added 'event' to my arguments on my left and right functions and it seemed to fix it. I'm guessing that's the other error you were talking about, right?

Comment: @GStut: yes, adding the `event` parameter to those functions are the errors I was speaking of.

Comment: well it fixed my problem, thank you. Why is it needed anyway?

Comment: @GStut: it's needed because tkinter always passes an object representing an event to a bound function.